# Push Notification is not showing when app is in background

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm trying to setup my application to receive push notification from GCM. When app is running in foreground the method in AppDelegate is calling:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
DLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
// This works only if the app started the GCM service
[[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

The example log is like that:

```
Notification received: {
aps =     {
    alert = "myk myk";
    badge = 2;
    sound = default;
    };
"gcm.message_id" = "0:1446730003823773%cc4efdeacc4efdea";
}
```

The problem is that when my application is in the background there is no information at all in notification center, no alert/banner is showing. I checked in settings->notifications and notifications are enabled for my app. When I enter to my app that was in the background then I have information about notification but this is not what I want.

I'm using iOS 9.0.1 with xCode 7.1
Why there is no notification banner when my app is in background?

Comment: when you app is in the background the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions comes into action, show your code there... did you fix this problem  ?

Answer (score 0):

Compare your payload with example from Apple site

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
    },
    "badge" : 5
},
"acme1" : "bar",
"acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

Alert json is probably wrong.